# Pymongo : Is there a way to using find and aggregate in same call while fetching data

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Have a db with 1 millions records with 105 columns

for find I'll use this and convert it into df

```
data=mydb.data.find({ "$and": [ {"age" : {"$gte" : "35", "$lte" : "60"}} ]
data = pd.DataFrame(list(data))
```

And to project only required columns I'm using this :

```
data=mydb.data.aggregate([
    {
        '$project': {
            'name': '$name', 
            'age': '$age'
        }
    }
])

data = pd.DataFrame(list(data))
```

these two are two separate calls. is there a way to make these two calls into one.

Comment: is `age` stored as string? shouldn't it be `"$gte": 35` and `"$lte": 60` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, the [projection parameter](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) allows for exactly this.

```
data=mydb.data.find({ "$and": [ {"age" : {"$gte" : "35", "$lte" : "60"}} ]}, {'name': 1, 'age': 1, '_id': 0})
```

Worked example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.mycollection.insert_one({'name': 'Foo', 'age': '40', 'address': 'bar'})

cursor = db.mycollection.find({ "$and": [ {"age" : {"$gte" : "35", "$lte" : "60"}} ]}, {'name': 1, 'age': 1, '_id': 0})
data = pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))
print(data)
```

gives:

```
  name age
0  Foo  40
```

Comment: index cannot be applied to Cursor instances

Comment: Worked example included. If you still get errors please produce a Minimal Reporduciible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to project on [`find()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) operation, you can pass the projection parameter as the second parameter.

```
mydb.data.find({ "$and": [ {"age" : {"$gte" : "35", "$lte" : "60" } } ] }, { "name": True, "age": True })
```

or

```
mydb.data.find({ "$and": [ {"age" : {"$gte" : "35", "$lte" : "60" } } ] }, ["name", "age"])
```

You can also use filter in an aggregation pipeline using the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage.

```
mydb.data.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': { '$and': [ {'age' : {'$gte' : '35', '$lte' : '60' } } ] }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            'name': '$name', 
            'age': '$age'
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: index 'age' cannot be applied to Cursor instances